# Incompatible type error. found java.lang.Object required :Item

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing a generic code as follows:

```
class Link<Item>
   {
      public Item dData;
      public Link next;
      public Link(Item d)
       {
         dData=d;
       }
     public void displayLink()
       {
         System.out.println(dData);
       }
    }
   ............
   Link delete=first;
   1>Item temp=delete.dData;// This code gives the error(mentioned at the title)
   2>Item temp=(Item)delete.dData; //This code works fine (With a warning no error)
```

Why does line 1 gives error { Incompatible type error. found java.lang.Object required :Item }, when the following code works absolutely fine?

```
  public class Stack<Item>
   {
     private Node first = null;
     private class Node
      {
        Item item;
        Node next;
      }
     public boolean isEmpty()
      {      return first == null; }
     public void push(Item item)
      {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
      }
     public Item pop()
      {
        Item item = first.item;// This statement works fine, then why not statement 1?
        first = first.next;
        return item;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should change your class declaration from `class Link<Item>` to `class Link<E>`. You could use some other letter like `T` but don't use `Item` to denote the type parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `Item` as a generic type parameter in your `Link` class.  However, your code that uses `Link` uses the raw form of the class, when you use such code as `Link delete=first;` and `public Link next;`.  When the *raw* form of a class is used, then all generics in the class, even unrelated generics, undergo type erasure.  Your `public Item dData;` is now effectively `public Object dData;`, and you can't assign an `Object` to an `Item` without casting.

The second code works because the generic type parameter `Item` is in scope and you aren't accessing `dData` and relying on its type.

Also, it's a bad idea to name a generic type parameter the same name as an existing name.  Usually, generic type parameters are single, capital letters, e.g.

```
class Link<T>
```

Also, use that generic type parameter elsewhere.

```
public T dData;
public Link<T> next;
public Link(T d)
{
   dData=d;
}
```

And instead of `Link delete=first;`, try `Link<T> delete=first;`.

Comment: @rgettman... sorry its not working. I tried Link<Item> delete=first but not working

Comment: and also why the second program works fine...they are on the same line I guess?

Comment: How did you declare `first` in that first piece of code?  Is it declared with a generic type parameter?